# How to run py.test and linters in `python setup.py test`

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest, setup.py

I have a project with a `setup.py` file. I use `pytest` as the testing framework and I also run various linters on my code (`pep8`, `pylint`, `pydocstyle`, `pyflakes`, etc). I use `tox` to run these in several Python versions, as well as build documentation using `Sphinx`.

I would like to run my test suites as well as the linters on my source code with the `python setup.py test` task. If I acheive this, I will then just use `python setup.py test` as the command for running tests in my `tox.ini` file.

So my questions are:

1. Is it reasonable / good practice to do these actions with `python setup.py test`? Or should I just use some other tool for that, like writing those command directly in `tox`?
2. How do I get `setup.py` to do these actions in the `test` task?

I know `py.test` has integration instructions for `setup.py test` (here: http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractices.html#integrating-with-setuptools-python-setup-py-test-pytest-runner), but I'm looking for a more "arbitrary CLI commands" route, since I want to run several tools.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** I personally prefer tox for these tasks, because

- it will also check if your deps install properly (on all py-versions)
- it can test your code with multiple python-versions (virtualenv)

And with your setup (since you're already using tox) i don't really see the benefits of writing `python setup.py test` instead of the exact test-commands into your `tox.ini`, because it will just add some more complexitiy (new users/contributors have to search two files (`tox.ini` and `setup.py`) for tests/tools running instead of one (`tox.ini`).

---

**2.**

> To use this command, your project’s tests must be wrapped in a unittest
>     test suite by either a function, a TestCase class or method, or a module
>     or package containing TestCase classes.

[setuptools#test](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#test)

Answer (score 1):

#### How to make `setup.py test` do `tox` stuff

```
import sys
import os

if sys.argv[-1] == 'test':
    try:
        import tox
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError('You should install `tox` before run `test`')
    sys.exit(os.system('tox'))
```

Looks not good, but you have a point. Continiue to use `tox.ini` for configure your tests environment and runners (as `flake8`, `coverage`, etc.) Because `tox` is good at stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more custom commands to your setup.py file like this:

```
class FooCommand(distutils.cmd.Command):
    ...

setup(
    cmdclass={
        'foo': FooCommand,
    }
)
```

however, note that there are already a set of commands you could use, and some runners you can include.

```
setup(
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner'] # gives you a new pytest command
)
```

Find out by running `python setup.py --help-commands`

```
Extra commands:
  ...
  pytest            run unit tests after in-place build
```