# Can py.test test docstring for the numpy style?

Tags: python, pytest, numpydoc

My pytest.ini currently looks like this:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --doctest-modules --cov=. --cov-report html --pep8 --flakes
doctest_encoding = utf-8
```

So I already test for PEP8. But I would also like to test the docstrings for numpydoc format:

- Are all parameters named in the correct order?
- If there is a return statement, is there also `Returns` in the docstring?
- ...

Is this possible

Comment: I just found something for pylint: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42123798/562769

Comment: [pydocstyle](https://github.com/PyCQA/pydocstyle/pull/226) has implemented the checks using `convention=numpy`.

Comment: @phd If you tell me how to add it to my `pytest.ini` this would be the answer to the question.

Comment: Add `pydocstyle` to your `requirements-dev.txt`, install it and run the command `pydocstyle $TOPLEVEL_MODULE` where `$TOPLEVEL_MODULE` is the top-level module of your project. I doubt `pydocstyle` can be integrated with `pytest`.

Comment: This is a case where [tox shines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239628/how-to-run-py-test-and-linters-in-python-setup-py-test).